# How can i update my Project Template from Visual Studio 2010 to support Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Me and my team were using Visual Studio 2010 as C#/.NET IDE, but we decided to upgrade it to 2012, and thats what we did.

We have a bunch of Project Templates previously created, on Visual Studio 2010.

How can we create/convert those for the 2012 version of the IDE ?

I've tried this [link from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx) but got no luck because my Visual Studio does not shows the VSIX Project option in this step :

```
On the File menu, click New and then click Project. Select either Visual Basic or Visual C#, select Extensibility, and then select VSIX Project.
```

Any tip / How to ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install VS2012 SDK?

Comment: No i haven't. Downloading it right now, lets see where it goes after that. Thanks Jose

Comment: Did you complete this?  Details?

Comment: No, i haven't. I gave up trying to solve it